# Dump the stack in Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, stack

Is there a way to dump the stack  of a program while debugging in ollydbg and store the result in a file  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alt + k -> right click -> copy to clipboard whole table -> paste to notepad -> save
```